# mvc3 using windows authentication - have to restart IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I just finished an MVC3 project using windows authenication.  Everything was working fine on my local machine however once I deployed to IIS7 it wouldn't pick up any user.  But after restarting IIS everything seems to work now.  Does anybody know why that is? Or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you just have to restart. You probably could have gotten away with just recycling the worker process.

As for the reason, probably because you created the iis application instance without an existing web.config in there, then when you deployed your site, IIS wasn't configured to watch for changes (because the file previously didn't exist), so it didn't know about the update.